# Lavalink, Pomice, Nextcord : pomice.exceptions.NodeConnectionFailure: The connection to node 'MAIN' failed. Correctly PORT, IP,Password

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying almost everything

Change the Port,
Turn off the Firewall,
Restarted lavalink,

Correctly Password, IP, Port

This is my code (Part of connection)

```py
async def start_nodes(self):
await self.bot.wait_until_ready() # Wait a bit until bot ready then connect node
await self.pomice.create_node(bot=self.bot, host='127.0.0.1', port='2333', 
                                         password='youshallnotpass', identifier='MAIN')
print(f"Node is ready!") # Print when node its ready
```

My yml connection part code

```
server: # REST and WS server
  port: 2333 # PORT
  address: 127.0.0.1 # IP
lavalink:
  server:
    password: "youshallnotpass" # Passowrd
    sources:
      youtube: true
      bandcamp: true
      soundcloud: true
      twitch: true
      vimeo: true
      http: true
```